# TERASOLUNA　Todoアプリケーション　mavenを用いたプロジェクト生成できちんとコンテンツが生成されずにいます

Tags: java, api

[こちらのtodoリストを生成するアプリ](https://terasolunaorg.github.io/guideline/1.0.3.RELEASE/ja/TutorialTodo/index.html#id3)の構築を行おうとしています。
その環境構築に際して、チュートリアルの通りに行かず困っております。
まずコマンドプロンプトで、プロジェクトの作成をしようと
Mavenをダウンロード
コマンドプロンプトでmvn archetype:generate -B^を実行

そして以下のログが生成され無事にプロジェクトが作成されてeclipse上に
インポートできました。
しかし、実際にできたプロジェクトを開いてみると
このようにデータやファイルがきちんと整備されていない状況になっています。

[image: 現状でインポートしたプロジェクト]

```
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive co
ntains): 1043:
Choose org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart version:
1: 1.0-alpha-1
2: 1.0-alpha-2
3: 1.0-alpha-3
4: 1.0-alpha-4
5: 1.0
6: 1.1
Choose a number: 6:
Define value for property 'groupId': todo
Define value for property 'artifactId': todo
Define value for property 'version' 1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
Define value for property 'package' todo: :
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: todo
artifactId: todo
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: todo
 Y: : y
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype:
 maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: C:\Users\hironori
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: todo
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: todo
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: todo
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: todo
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: C:\Users\hironori\todo
```

また再度、プロジェクトをmvnで作成しても

```
More? Y
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.266 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-20T14:53:37+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/77M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (C:\Users\hironori). Please verify you invoked Maven from the
 correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProject
Exception
```

というように失敗してしまいます。

現状できちんと、チュートリアルサンプルのようにプロジェクトを過不足なく落とし込むにはどうづればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\hironori)`というエラーが出ていますね。`C:\Users\hironori\todo`の一つ上のディレクトリで`mvn`コマンドを実行したために、エラーになっているように見えます。